# How to test view pager swipe gesture in Android using Espresso 2.2

Tags: android, automation, android-viewpager, android-espresso

I am writing automation test for View pager using Espresso 2.2 in which I need to test the swipe functionality.

I have written the below code:

```
 @LargeTest
 public class FirstActivityTest {

 @Rule
 public ActivityTestRule<FirstActivity> firstActivityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>( FirstActivity.class);

@Test
public void testViewPagerSwipeFunctionality() throws InterruptedException{


   onView(withId(R.id.tv_commu)).check(matches(withText(R.string.first_screen_text)));

   onView(withId(R.id.tv_skip)).check(matches(withText(R.string.skip))) ;

   onView(withId(R.id.radio_button_first)).check(matches(isChecked()));
   onView(withId(R.id.view_pager)).perform(swipLeft());

   onView(withId(R.id.radio_button_second))
            .check(matches(isChecked()));
   onView(withId(R.id.tv_comp)).check(matches(withText(R.string.second_screen_text)));

   onView(withId(R.id.tv_skip)).check(matches(withText(R.string.skip))) ;

   onView(withId(R.id.view_pager)).perform(swipeLeft());

   onView(withId(R.id.radio_button_third))
            .check(matches(isChecked()));
   onView(withId(R.id.tv_skip)).check(matches(withText(R.string.skip))) ;
    onView(withId(R.id.tv_person)).check(matches(withText(R.string.third_screen_text)));}}
```

However the method swipeLeft() is not getting resolved. Please let me know where I am doing wrong? Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, is this problem resolved? Please add more info about problem you had faced

Comment: Yeah, its been resolved, need to do static import.

Answer (score 13):

You have to import swipeLeft() like:

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.swipeLeft;
```

Side note:
The example code has swipLeft() rather than swipeLeft().

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are able to swipe, you will see the action but the test will still fail. By default, Espresso validate 90% visibility and it fails otherwise. You need to customized the visibility yourself, basically lower it. Please refer to this solution: 
[Espresso: How to test SwipeRefreshLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505953/espresso-how-to-test-swiperefreshlayout)
Hope this helps!