# Espresso: How to test SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

My app reloads data when a down-swipe is done on a `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Now I try to test this with Android Test Kit / Espresso like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_refresh_layout)).perform(swipeDown());
```

Unfortunately this fails with

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'fast swipe'
on view 'with id: my.app.package:id/my_refresh_layout'.
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view
does not match one or more of the following constraints:
at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.
Target view: "SwipeRefreshLayout{id=2131689751, res-name=my_refresh_layout, visibility=VISIBLE,
width=480, height=672, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true,
is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, 
is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0,
child-count=2}"
```

Of course, the layout is visible and swiping manually works, but I'm unsure if I'm doing something wrong? The layout spans the whole screen, so it *should* really be possible for Espresso to do some action on it.

Comment: how to do this with kakao framework

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Sleeping over it sometimes helps. The underlying reason was that the to-be-swiped view was only 89% visible to the user, while Espresso's swipe actions internally demand 90%. So the solution is to wrap the swipe action into another action and override these constraints by hand, like this:

```
public static ViewAction withCustomConstraints(final ViewAction action, final Matcher<View> constraints) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return constraints;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return action.getDescription();
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            action.perform(uiController, view);
        }
    };
}
```

This can then be called like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_refresh_layout))
    .perform(withCustomConstraints(swipeDown(), isDisplayingAtLeast(85)));
```